# NativeScript - Native UI access

Tags: android, api, user-interface, mobile, nativescript

I dont get it yet.

In NativeScript/Android can I use all the UI components even if there is nota bundle (nativescript plugin). ?

I ask this question because Telerik offers a special UI package, with elements that already exists in native Android UI.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short and simple: Yes, you can access the native UI even if there is not a plugin.

Those plugins are to provide some helpers so yo don't need to type everything for both platforms on your own.

For example, if you want to create a label on an Android platform, without using the plugin, is as easy as:

`new android.widget.TextView(this._context);`

You can take a look at all the UI components in their GitHub to see how the plugins work in both platforms: 
https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/tree/master/tns-core-modules/ui